# How to provide selection if multiple controls on a view?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In texts about a selections (like this https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html) it is usually said to provide selection by commands like this:

```
getSite().setSelectionProvider(tableviewer);
```

This is good if a view has only one control, for example, `TableViewer`.

But what to do if view has several controls?

I can't delegate selection providing to any ONE of them. Probably I should track which one is selected and switch selection provider appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a selection provider which wraps all of your viewers (or other selection providers) and switches between them automatically. Unfortunately, something like that isn't included in the framework.